# content does not stay inside div

Tags: css, html

I've got a div where the content of the div "escapes" the div.

if for example i put in something like ssssssssssssssssssssss (and so on :P) it just goes over the divs edge instead of breaking and continuing on the next line.

css:

```
#content {
 position:absolute;
 width: 855px;
 padding: 195px;
 padding-top: 0px;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to the CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: For the browsers which doesn't support it (the ancient ones), you may want to consider to add an `overflow-x:scroll;` though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow property:

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp